# Quantifying difference in model performance?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, validation

Probably a very basic question that's been asked before, but ...

I have a set of candidate models (mixed-effects linear regressions) I'm fitting to 1/0 (presence/absence) data in R using `glmer`. Using AIC scores and delta-AICs, I can determine which models have the best support and relatively how much better they are from the others. But I would like a more intuitive way to describe how much of an improvement the top model is over a lower model. For example, I'd like to be able to make a statement like, "Model One performed 10% better than Model Two" or "the inclusion of this variable improved increased model performance by 10%"

Here's what my AIC output looks like:

```
Model selection based on AICc:

                  K   AICc Delta_AICc AICcWt Cum.Wt      LL
canopy + nest hab 4 561.34       0.00   0.48   0.48 -276.64
canopy + f hab    4 562.33       0.99   0.29   0.78 -277.13
canopy alone      3 564.32       2.98   0.11   0.89 -279.14
nest hab alone    3 565.46       4.12   0.06   0.95 -279.71
canopy + age      4 565.84       4.51   0.05   1.00 -278.89
```

I'm particularly interested in comparing the top model the "nest hab alone" model.

Is it possible to calculate something like this? And if so, how?

Comment: You first need to define what you mean by "model performance". Usually, I'd understand that as predictive performance which would mean you should focus on (cross)validation instead of AIC.

Comment: Agree with Roland about defining model performance. Also remember that nested mixed models can be formally tested using likelihood ratio tests (you list the `LL`, which I am assuming is the log likelihood). In R, use `anova()` for this.

Comment: Yes, good point about defining performance. I'll look into cross-validation. Since this a RSF model, AIC is pretty standard for selected the top models(s) and k-squared cross validation is common for assessing predictive ability. But it looks like cross validation will give me R^2, which is helpful but still not very tangible. Is there a way I can translate that into how much better one model predicts used sites than another?